How to determine if a curve defined by an equation is closed
This problem arises in the construction of special hypersurfaces, I want to know if I can find a closed curve that satisfies the equation.
The curve satisfies the following equation:
$\begin{cases}
x'(s)=\cos(\theta(s))\\
r'(s)=\sin(\theta(s))\\
\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}\left(\frac{\cos\theta}{r}\right)^2\theta'=x\sin\theta-r\cos\theta+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{6}\left(\frac{\cos\theta}{r}\right)^3\\
x(0)=0\\
r(0)=r_0\\
\theta(0)=0\\
\end{cases}$
Where $\theta$ is the angle between the tangent to the curve and the $x$-axis, and $n\ge 4$
I used mathmatica to plot some special cases.
when $n=4$:

But when I increase the arc length s there are some problems with the curve drawing because the curve transforms too fast.

I've tried different $n,r_0$, and it's similar.
From these examples I think that perhaps there are no closed curves, but how do I prove it?
I want to analyse the periodicity of the orbit through a dynamical system approach. If the orbit is unbounded there is no periodicity and the curve is unbounded from the image. I tried to make some transformations to the equations and attempted to use the Lyapunov function $E=x^2+r^2$ to prove unboundedness, but still don't know how to prove it.
Here are some rewrites of my equations that might be helpful in solving this problem
$$\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}\left(\frac{x'}{r}\right)^2\theta'=xr'-rx'+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{6}\left(\frac{x'}{r}\right)^3$$
$$\theta'=\frac{2}{(n-1)(n-2)}\left(\frac{r}{x'}\right)^2(xr'-rx')+\frac{n-3}{3}\frac{x'}{r}=-\frac{x''}{r'}=\frac{r''}{x'}$$
where $xr'-rx'=x^2\left(\frac{r}{x}\right)'=-r^2\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)'$

Since you mention the $x$-axis, I suppose $x$ is intended to be the $x$-coordinate. You also use $r, \theta$, except that the only one you explain is $\theta$, but give it an interpretation different from polar coordinates (where it would be the angle to the point, not to the tangent at the point). So what is $r$? Is it the radial distance from the origin, as in polar coordinates, or is it something else?

Thanks for that, sorry I didn't clarify my question, here the closed curve I'm looking for is in the x-r plane

So, cartesian coordinates $(x, r)$?

Yes, it's the cartesian coordinates $(x,r)$ , in this problem $r$ is just like $y$ . In the original question of this problem maybe it has a meaning like radius, but I'm not sure.

Letting $A = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}2, B = A\frac{n-3}3$, the two equations $$x'^2 + r'^2 = 1\A\dfrac{x'r''}{r^2} = xr'-rx' + B \dfrac{x'^3}{r^2}$$ include everything in your problem while removing one of the functions. By a clever enough change of variables, you should be able to reduce it to a single D.E. in one function. That D.E. is non-linear, but likely has solutions.

Thanks for the advice, I'll give it a try

I notice that my second equation should have $r^3$, not $r^2$, in the second denominator. But you've likely already spotted that.
